# How to start Alarm Manager with service in android

Tags: android

I have searched a lot and always find that alarm manager always start with the help of broadcast reciever not directly with services. I want to know why is it so, kindly tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Pending Intent alarm Manager can start a service, broadcast receiver or an Activity.

```
getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int),
getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), 
getService(Context, int, Intent, int);
```

You can use any of the method of pending Intent and your alarm will prompt either of activity or receiver or service.